# For flutter do you need the android and ios folder if you are only using the desktop platform?

Tags: flutter

Trying to find ways to speed up the Flutter build and make the application smooth. If you have suggestions for a different framework, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

No. When creating a new flutter project, you can just define the platforms relevant to your project, e.g:

`flutter create -t app --project-name=hello_world --platforms=windows,linux,macos`